# what do you call that html technique wherein you tag an id to an href? (ie href="#id" then clicking it will lead to the tagged element)

Tags: html

i really need to do a search about it for a project and modify its behavior such that it achieves a smooth scroll.

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example for people to work with. You should also take our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no name specifically given to the technique when you use an anchor tag to navigate to an ID within the page. You may also use JQuery to have animation/effects for your navigation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'name' for it as such. You're linking to an 'anchor' on the page.

I think you're looking for a technique known as [smooth scrolling](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/), which shows the page scrolling instead of just jumping to it immediately.